# How to create a .Plist that contains key ==> Value?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, plist, key-value

In my application I need to read data from plist also  I need to know how to create the plist that contains the key-value data. And is there a better way to read info (key-value)?

Comment: @ThomasW : a better way of reading saved key-value data from iphone other than plist

Comment: Do you have the application Property List Editor?

Comment: It depends on what your goals are. If it is performance plist is good because it is stored in a binary format and is fast. If you're looking for cross-platform compatibility you might want to go with JSON or YAML.

Comment: @grc: no I don't have it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to read plist data is to use NSDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Similarly you can write it out using:

```
[myDict writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```